# Mock directory attributes using c#

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, case

I am writing a unit test case for my application. I want to mock **Attributes** of DirectoryInfo.

Please, any one help me to write mock unit test case for following method.
Method:

```
 public void CheckPermissionOnFolder(string strDrivePath)
    {
        string strObjectName = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strObjectName).Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
        }
        catch
        {}
    }
```

Comment: How about abstracting the pieces you  need for your application's business logic? Mocking objects you don't control can be a painful game.

Comment: Can you please shows us method you want to test and test you wrote. What is the purpose of `CheckPermissionOnFolder`?  Could you show its full implementation?

Comment: Hello Bojan Komazec, This is my final method. purpose of this method is to check the permission of new folder creation on my repository.

Comment: So, Bojan Komazec, while i am testing my application. i want to write the test case  for this method. i will try to  mock "Directory.CreateDirectory" method. but it is not supported.

Comment: Other  thing is that i am able to create the wrapper class for the Directory. but how to mock the Attributes property.

I am avoiding the all path related dependency in my test case. So, to give physical path for test case is not possible.

Comment: How does your method communicate error (or any result) to its caller? It returns `void` and swallows exceptions.